# Display form errors in Django combine view

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I've created combine ListView and FormView. If I invoking form valid method everything works fine, but if form is not valid and I try to initialize form_invalid method and redirect to MainView to display form errors, I get error.

views.py

```
class MainView(ListView, FormMixin):
    """
    Main which display all posts
    """
    #  Setting template name
    template_name = 'post/main.html'
    #  Setting view model
    model = Post
    # Setting pagination
    paginate_by = 5
    #  Setting form class
    form_class = PostForm

    #  Overriding get_context_data method
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MainView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.form_class()
        context['trends'] = Tag.objects.all().order_by('posts')
        return context

    #  Handling post sending
    def post(self, request):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            self.form_valid(form)
            return redirect('main')
        else:
            self.form_invalid(form)
            return redirect('main')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        #  Getting body text from form
        text = form.cleaned_data['body']
        #  Getting actual logged in user
        author = self.request.user
        #  Getting image file
        image_file = form.cleaned_data['image_file']
        #  Getting image_url
        image_url = form.cleaned_data['image_url']
        #  Creating post instance and saving
        post = Post(text=text, author=author, image_file=image_file, image_url=image_url)
        post.save()
```

error

```
AttributeError at /main/

'MainView' object has no attribute 'object_list'
```

post/main.html

```
    <!--Post column-->
    <section class="col-sm-7">

        <!--Iterating through posts-->
        {% for post in object_list %}
        {{ post.text}}
        {% endfor %}

    </section>
```

Comment: Does swapping around the parents' names help? `class MainView(FormMixin, ListView):`.

Comment: Seems like you're trying to access `object_list` attribute from your view instead of using it as template variable. Can you show the template `'post/main.html'`..?

Comment: @mariodev Okay, I added it.

Comment: @AlexMorozov I did it and seems to have no effect.

Comment: @PawełKosiński Can you please include full traceback if possible.. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `ListView` and the `FormMixin` don't play well together out-of-box, so you need to change your view a bit. Try this sample base view:

```
class CreateListView(CreateView, ListView):
    def form_invalid(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.get(self, request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = CreateView.get_context_data(self, **kwargs)
        context.update(
            super(FormListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        )
        return context


class MainView(CreateListView):
    template_name = 'post/main.html'
    model = Post
    paginate_by = 5
    form_class = PostForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('this-view-name')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(MainView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['trends'] = Tag.objects.all().order_by('posts')
        return context
```